# Extrair arquivo .zip Protegido com senha

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, arquivo-zip, senhas

Estou fazendo uma macro VBA no excel, para extrair arquivos .zip (que seria uma barbada de fazer), exceto quando o arquivo é protegido. Pesquisei em tudo que é canto, há vários tutoriais para extrair .zip protegido, mas nenhum deles é para quando o arquivo têm senha.
Então achei umas dicas para usar comandos Shell (Descupem, mas nunca usei Shell na VBA), então achei o seguinte código, e não consigo :

```
Public Sub ShellAndWait(ByVal PathName As String, Optional WindowState)
    Dim hProg As Long
    Dim hProcess As Long, ExitCode As Long
    'fill in the missing parameter and execute the program
    If IsMissing(WindowState) Then WindowState = 1
    hProg = Shell(PathName, WindowState)
    'hProg is a "process ID under Win32. To get the process handle:
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, hProg)
    Do
        'populate Exitcode variable
        GetExitCodeProcess hProcess, ExitCode
        DoEvents
    Loop While ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE
End Sub
'With this example you browse to the zip or 7z file you want to unzip
'The zip file will be unzipped in a new folder in: Application.DefaultFilePath
'Normal if you have not change it this will be your Documents folder
'The name of the folder that the code create in this folder is the Date/Time
'You can change this folder to this if you want to use a fixed folder:
'NameUnZipFolder = "C:\Users\Ron\TestFolder\"
'Read the comments in the code about the commands/Switches in the ShellStr
'There is no need to change the code before you test it
Sub A_UnZip_Zip_File_Browse()
    Dim PathZipProgram As String, NameUnZipFolder As String
    Dim FileNameZip As Variant, ShellStr As String
    'Path of the Zip program
    PathZipProgram = "C:\program files\7-Zip\"
    If Right(PathZipProgram, 1) <> "\" Then
        PathZipProgram = PathZipProgram & "\"
    End If

    'Check if this is the path where 7z is installed.
    If Dir(PathZipProgram & "7zFM.exe") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please find your copy of 7z.exe and try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create path and name of the normal folder to unzip the files in
    'In this example we use: Application.DefaultFilePath
    'Normal if you have not change it this will be your Documents folder
    'The name of the folder that the code create in this folder is the Date/Time
    NameUnZipFolder = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\TESTE"
    'You can also use a fixed path like
    'NameUnZipFolder = "C:\Users\Ron\TestFolder"

    'Select the zip file (.zip or .7z files)
    FileNameZip = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Zip Files, *.zip", _
                                              MultiSelect:=False, Title:="Select the file that you want to unzip")

    'Unzip the files/folders from the zip file in the NameUnZipFolder folder
    If FileNameZip = False Then
                MsgBox FileNameZip
    Else
        'There are a few commands/Switches that you can change in the ShellStr
        'We use x command now to keep the folder stucture, replace it with e if you want only the files
        '-aoa Overwrite All existing files without prompt.
        '-aos Skip extracting of existing files.
        '-aou aUto rename extracting file (for example, name.txt will be renamed to name_1.txt).
        '-aot auto rename existing file (for example, name.txt will be renamed to name_1.txt).
        'Use -r if you also want to unzip the subfolders from the zip file
        'You can add -ppassword if you want to unzip a zip file with password (only 7zip files)
        'Change "*.*" to for example "*.txt" if you only want to unzip the txt files
        'Use "*.xl*" for all Excel files: xls, xlsx, xlsm, xlsb
        ShellStr = PathZipProgram & "7zFM.exe x -aoa -r" _
                 & " " & Chr(34) & FileNameZip & Chr(34) _
                 & " -o" & Chr(34) & NameUnZipFolder & Chr(34) & " " & "*.*"

        ShellAndWait ShellStr, vbHide
        MsgBox "Look in " & NameUnZipFolder & " for extracted files"
    End If
End Sub
```

Onde ele diz para incluir o "-ppassword" não consegui fazer, ele não retorna. Tentei fazer com um arquivo sem senha, nesse mesmo código, e ele não extrai, só não entendi por quê. Coloquei o .exe do 7zip conforme meu diretório, só que quando ele chega nesse passo de extrair, ele para e não traz retorno.
No caso abaixo, "15100086230090" é a senha, então ficaria -p15100086230090 correto?

```
    ShellStr = PathZipProgram & "7zFM.exe x -aoa -r -p15100086230090" _
             & " " & Chr(34) & FileNameZip & Chr(34) _
             & " -o" & Chr(34) & NameUnZipFolder & Chr(34) & " " & "*.*"
```

Answer (score -1):

Utilize o [programa de exemplo do Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winfiles/7zip_unzipexamples.txt), um dos melhores sites para Excel VBA, junto com o [Cpearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx).

Este programa usa o Shell do Windows e para descompactar, utiliza o [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/), em que o caminho de instalação do programa deve ser informado. Mas se foi instalado do modo padrão, normalmente estará em "C:\program files\7-Zip\".

#### Problema

O Ron de Bruin pede para utilizar o `-ppassword` para arquivos com extensão `.7z`, no caso de arquivos zip, utilize o `-p`.

Então condicionais de como criar o `ShellStr` podem ser realizadas, primeiro para verificar se precisa de senha ou não. E depois, com o FileSystemObject(FSO), verificar se a extensão é .7z ou .zip, para alterar no comando shell a inserção de senha.

#### Passos do Programa

1. Insere o caminho do 7-zip e verificar se está correto
2. O diretório em que os arquivos serão salvos (`NameUnZipFolder`)
3. Escolhe o caminho do arquivo zip (`FileNameZip`)
4. Insere a senha (`senha`)
5. Chama a função `ShellAndWait` para extrair os arquivos

> No caso do programa travar com loop infinito em `ShellAndWait`, o erro está no comando
>   Shell Script enviado, há algum erro na sua `ShellStr`

#### Código

O código foi alterado para funcionar corretamente para programas com senha, em que o programa deve ser escolhido.

```
' Declaração com compatibilidade entre 64 e 32 bits
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
        lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
        lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#End If


Public Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400
Public Const STILL_ACTIVE = &H103


Public Sub ShellAndWait(ByVal PathName As String, Optional WindowState)
    Dim hProg As Long
    Dim hProcess As Long, ExitCode As Long
    'fill in the missing parameter and execute the program
    'preenche o parâmetro que falta e executa o programa
    If IsMissing(WindowState) Then WindowState = 1
    hProg = Shell(PathName, WindowState)
    'hProg is a "process ID under Win32. To get the process handle:
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, hProg)
    Do
        'populate Exitcode variable
        GetExitCodeProcess hProcess, ExitCode
        DoEvents
    Loop While ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE
End Sub

Sub A_UnZip_Zip_File_Browse()
    Dim PathZipProgram As String, NameUnZipFolder As String
    Dim FileNameZip As Variant, ShellStr As String, senha As String

    'Caminho do programa zip, neste caso o 7-Zip
    PathZipProgram = "C:\program files\7-Zip\"
    If Right(PathZipProgram, 1) <> "\" Then
        PathZipProgram = PathZipProgram & "\"
    End If

    'Verifica se o 7-Zip está realmente instalado neste diretório
    If Dir(PathZipProgram & "7z.exe") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Por favor encontre a sua cópia do 7z.exe e tente novamente"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Cria uma pasta no diretório padrão "Documentos", com a data e hora
    NameUnZipFolder = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd h-mm-ss")
    'Caso deseje alterar a pasta em que o arquivo será descompactado, altere o caminho para:
    'NameUnZipFolder = "C:\Users\PastaDesejada\TestFolder"

    'Selecione o arquivo zip (.zip ou .7z)
    FileNameZip = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Zip Files, *.zip, 7z Files, *.7z", _
                                              MultiSelect:=False, Title:="Select the file that you want to unzip")

    'Senha
    senha = "suasenha"

    'Unzip
    If FileNameZip = False Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        'There are a few commands/Switches that you can change in the ShellStr
        'We use x command now to keep the folder stucture, replace it with e if you want only the files
        '-aoa Overwrite All existing files without prompt.
        '-aos Skip extracting of existing files.
        '-aou aUto rename extracting file (for example, name.txt will be renamed to name_1.txt).
        '-aot auto rename existing file (for example, name.txt will be renamed to name_1.txt).
        'Use -r if you also want to unzip the subfolders from the zip file
        'You can add -ppassword if you want to unzip a zip file with password (only 7zip files)
        'Change "*.*" to for example "*.txt" if you only want to unzip the txt files
        'Use "*.xl*" for all Excel files: xls, xlsx, xlsm, xlsb
        ShellStr = PathZipProgram & "7z.exe x -aoa -r" _
                 & " " & adiciona_aspas(FileNameZip) _
                 & " -p" & adiciona_aspas(senha) _
                 & " -o" & adiciona_aspas(NameUnZipFolder) & " " & "*.*"
        'Se não possuir senha, exclua a linha de senha '& " -p" & adiciona_aspas(senha) _'
        'Então você pode criar condicionais para verificar se possui ou não senha.

        ShellAndWait ShellStr, vbHide
        MsgBox "Procure os arquivos extraídos em " & NameUnZipFolder

    End If
End Sub

Function adiciona_aspas(str) As String
    adiciona_aspas = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function
```